# Highcharts Polar charts display labels on specific tick quarters

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, custom-controls

Considering that my data array is always composed of 4 elements as :

```
  var data = [
{"type":"column","name":"My Label 1","y":38.9500000000003,"color":"#7cb342"},           
{"type":"column","name":"My Label 2","y":30,"color":"#7cb342"},                                     {"type":"column","name":"My Label 3","y":51.85,"color":"#fbc02d"},                  {"type":"column","name":"My Label 4","y":55.2999999999997,"color":"#fbc02d"}];
```

I want to know how to set my data names (`data.name`) each 45 degrees tick interval to keep them well positioned ?

Here is the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/eento/7rupgxde/4/

It's important for me to display only those labels & keep them inside the global highchart container.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific, or provide an illustration of what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use renderer to render those labels, for example, create two methods (one to add labels and one to position them):

```
function renderLabels(chart) {
  var alignments = ['right', 'right', 'left', 'left'];
  $.each(chart.series[0].points, function(i, point) {
    point.myName = chart.renderer.text(point.name, -9999, -9999).attr({
      align: alignments[i],
      color: 'black'
    }).add();
  });
}

function positionLabels(chart, anim) {
  var positions = [
    // top right label
    [chart.plotLeft + chart.plotWidth, chart.plotTop],
    // bottom right label
    [chart.plotLeft + chart.plotWidth, chart.plotTop + chart.plotHeight],
    // bottom left label
    [chart.plotLeft, chart.plotTop + chart.plotHeight],
    // top left label
    [chart.plotLeft, chart.plotTop], 
  ]
  $.each(chart.series[0].points, function(i, point) {
    if (point.myName) {
      point.myName[(anim ? 'animate' : 'attr')]({
        x: positions[i][0],
        y: positions[i][1],
      })
    }
  });
}
```

Then use those methods in `chart.events`:

```
chart: {
  polar: true,
  renderTo: 'container',
  backgroundColor: null,
  events: {
    load: function() {
      renderLabels(this);
      positionLabels(this, false);
    },
    redraw: function() {
      positionLabels(this, true);
    }
  }
},
```

And working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7rupgxde/7/

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    formatter: function() {
        return this.point.name;
    }
}
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/7rupgxde/5/

Comment: thats ok but i need to display these labels outside of the gridlines circiles (like the degrees)